# python3 mysqlclientをインストールしたい

Tags: mysql, macos, python3

MacOS10.13 python3
MySQLdbを使いたく、いろいろ調べた結果以下の2つのやり方で入れようとしたのですがどちらも失敗しました。どうすれば解決するでしょうか。

mysqlclient
pip install mysqlclient で実行するといかのようなエラーがでて失敗します。

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz (89kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 212kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-1D0Uuf/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 54, in get_config
        libraries = [dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith('-l')]
      File "setup_posix.py", line 12, in dequote
        if s[0] in "\"'" and s[0] == s[-1]:
    IndexError: string index out of range

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-1D0Uuf/mysqlclient/
```

libmysqlclient-dev
またapt-getによりsudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev　でいけるかなと思ったのですが以下のように見つからないとでてできませんでした。
apt-getをupdateしてからやっても同じ結果でした。

```
Reading Package Lists... Done
Building Dependency Tree... Done
E: Couldn't find package libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: Pythonはなにを使っていますか? apt-getがあるということは、finkでインストールしたものを使っているのでしょうか。

Comment: python3を使っています。その通りです。finkでインストールしました。